# FactoryGirl uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am strugging around an uninitialized constant error with FactoryGirl

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant Usernotactivated
```

I have the following in my factories.rb file

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :usernotactivated do
  name "foonotactiv"
  email "foonotactiv@example.com"
  password "secretnot"
  activated false
end
end
```

and the following in my spec

```
it "should redirect to activation alert when it signs me in with an inactivated account" do
user = FactoryGirl.build(:usernotactivated)
visit login_path
  fill_in 'Email', :with => usernotactivated.email
  fill_in 'Password', :with => usernotactivated.password
click_button 'Sign in'
expect(page).to have_content 'your account is not activated'
end
```

In both files rails_helper.rb and spec_helper.rb I have added those lines:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

I also tried

```
require 'factory_girl'
```

Somehow, I change "usernotactivated" with "user" I do not get this uninitialized constant error but I am not sure whether it is because "user" may be a protected name. Could anyone give me hint on where I should investigate this issue? Could you also tell me the different between the rails_helper file (which I require in all my spec) and the spec_helper file? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FactoryGirl builds instances of your models - by default, a factory named `:usernotactivated` will want to build an instance of a `Usernotactivated` model. You don't have this model in your app, so you're getting an error.

If instead this factory is supposed to generate an instance of your `User` model, you could either rename the factory to be `:user`, or add the class name option to your factory:

```
factory :user_not_activated, class: User do
```

Comment: The API has been changed, the syntax is now `factory :user_not_activated, class: User do`